# invoking function for each variadic template arguments and passing the result as constructor arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

So i want to generate a lambda that will invoke a constructor by retrieving the constructor's parameters from a factory.

I want to convert this code that works right now into a variadic template so it will work with any number of constructor parameters.

Any idea how to do this?

```
template <class Class>
struct Constructor
{
};


template <class Class>
struct Constructor< Class() >{
    static std::function<Class*()> Instanciator(Factory& factory)
    {
        return []{
            return new Class();
        };
    }
};

template <class Class, class Arg1>
struct Constructor< Class(Arg1) >{
    static std::function<Class*()> Instanciator(Factory& factory)
    {
        return []{
            return new Class(factory.Get<Arg1>());
        };
    }
};

template <class Class, class Arg1, class Arg2>
struct Constructor< Class(Arg1, Arg2) >{
    static std::function<Class*()> Instanciator(Factory& factory)
    {
        return []{
            return new Class(factory.Get<Arg1>(), factory.Get<Arg2>());
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: What have you tried?, because it sounds a little more like a "give me the code" question

Comment: exs, i don't have a compilable solution, i don't even know how that would look like. if you know how to solve this particular problem but you don't want to share then you can point me in the right direction. otherwise i can conclude that your comment sounds a little more like noise.

Comment: My only interest would be to help you to learn how to use it and help anyone else that might find it useful, but I think you would learn a lot more by reading a little more about the subject and come with a crude implementation by yourself before and then come with specific questions or errors that you encounter along the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class Class>
struct Constructor
{};

template <class Class, class...Args>
struct Constructor< Class(Args...) > {
  template<class Factory>
  std::function<Class*()> operator()(Factory& factory)const
  {
    return []{
      return new Class(factory.Get<Args>()...);
    };
  }
};
```

now `Constructor< Foo(Args...) >` is a function object of type `Factory -> std::function<Foo*()>`, where `Factory` supports `.Get<Args>()` for each `Args`.

Me, I'd also want to include the index in the `.Get<?>()` call, in case your class takes two `int` arguments or whatever.

I removed `Instanciator` and the `static` bit, because a class whose only purpose is to produce constructors doesn't need that noise.  Making it an invokable stateless function object is more idiomatic.

Comment: thank you yakk, i did not know that `factory.Get<Args>()...` is valid syntax